# How to remove namespace from Inherits Attribute without a Parser Error, Could not load type

Tags: asp.net

I've seen lots of posts about the Inherits Attribute, and the Parser Error "Could not load type"

I can get this working by putting "RootNamespace.PageName" for a specific page, where RootNamespace matches the Root namespace in my project properites.

But I would rather not put the namespace in there. i.e. I would rather put "PageName" than "Namespace.PageName".

I have a library project with a few DLLs and 10 or so .aspx and .ascx files. 
To get an update of my library project, other projects in my company copy the DLLs in and then copy the .aspx and .ascx files into a specific folder in their project.

Only problem is every time they copy they have to change the Namespace of the inherits attribute to match the root namesapce in their project.
If they don't do this, they get no compiler errors but just get a Parser error when they hit the libary .aspx and .ascx files.

This is very annoying, it seems very ridiculous that so many pages will not work if the project root namespace changes.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can make library pages and user controls for nuse withing other peoples projects?

Thanks,
Mike G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha! A colleague stumbled upon a way around this by accident...

OK I have a single shared "Library" project and many "normal" projects that make use of shared stuff from the Library...

1- Create a "Library" WebApplication that outputs a DLL, and put your web library code and also .ascxs and .aspx pages into the WebApplication project. 2- Reference the "Library" DLL in your "Normal" projects 3- Copy just the shared .aspx and .ascx files from "library" into the "normal" projects, but ... (important bit!) ... without the code behind

In our example we don't actually include the copied .ascx and .aspx files in the project (e.g. They're not referenced in the .vbproj file) and they don't get put in source control, they just get copied in from the library every time you build. We haven't experimented with what happens if you tell the project about the .aspx and .ascx files but they definitely load OK at run time.

So it does actually make sense no I think ab out it. 
Basically the root namespace of the .aspx files is unachanged it's just refers to classes in the referenced library DLL so it all works.